# MYSQL query single field two calls

Tags: php, mysql

I want to validate a query with two conditions for a field `last_login`.  It's a date field. I wanna check in the query where `last_login` between date ranges which is passing from another page and also i want to attach this to my existing query.

**users.last_login between adddate(now(),-7) and now().** I want to know how will i attach this to the existing query. My existing query is below:

```
  $data = "SELECT users.first_name FROM users INNER JOIN agencies ON
 users.agency_id=agencies.id where users.last_login between '".$_POST["fdate"]."' 
and '".$_POST["tdate"]."' group by agencies.name";
```

Comment: What error are u getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **()** and **AND** keyword

```
$data = "SELECT 
            users.first_name
        FROM
            users
                INNER JOIN
            agencies ON users.agency_id = agencies.id
        WHERE
            (users.last_login BETWEEN '".$_POST["fdate"]."' AND '".$_POST["tdate"]."')
                AND (users.last_login BETWEEN ADDDATE(NOW(), - 7) AND NOW())
        GROUP BY agencies.name";
```